# how to print current wallpaper path in windows 10 using python?

Tags: python

python program to print the current wallpaper path as output

i have tried this code but its not working

```
pip install py-wallpaper
```

```
from wallpaper import set_wallpaper, get_wallpaper
print(get_wallpaper())
set_wallpaper("location/to/image.jpg")
```

This shows the error that win-wallpaper is not regognised as internal or external command

how  to print the path of current wallpaper path in windows using python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library have a `bug`. To overcome follow these steps.

**1.** Open `wallpaper` library directory and create a file name `win-wallpaper.py`.
**2.** Add following code into newly create module .

```
import ctypes,win32con
def getWallpaper():
    ubuf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(512)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(win32con.SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER,len(ubuf),ubuf,0)
    return ubuf.value

print(getWallpaper())
```

**3.** Then use `pyinstaller` to convert `py` to `exe` file.
**Note:** Don't use `cmd` for `compile purpose` .

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w 'win-wallpaper.py'
```

**4.** From `dist` folder take `win-wallpaper.exe` file to main directory.
Now, it is good to go.

**But one thing you should not here, this library still not contain proper implementation of `set_wallpaper(path)` function**. This contain lots of bug so please use last code stuff.

---

### **If you don't want to use this library then use this code.**

```
import ctypes,win32con

def getWallpaper():
    ubuf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(512)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(win32con.SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER,len(ubuf),ubuf,0)
    return ubuf.value

def setWallpaper(path):
    changed = win32con.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | win32con.SPIF_SENDCHANGE
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(win32con.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,path,changed)
```